# Table - bold and normal lines (centering)

Tags: tables

How can I solve this graphical problem please?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
    \caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs - přirozené pozadí}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{?c|c|c|c|c|c?}
        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

\multicolumn{1}{?c?}{\cellcolor{gray!25}$PEAK$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{c?}{\centering \cellcolor{gray!25}$E_{tab}$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{c?}{\centering Zdroj \cellcolor{gray!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c?}{\centering \cellcolor{gray!25}$FWHM$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1.2cm}?}{\centering $NET$ \cellcolor{gray!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1.2cm}?}{$GROSS$ \cellcolor{gray!25}}\\         

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
609,35& 609,31& \multirow{4}{*}{$^{214}$Bi} & 1,38&   539&    4675\\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1120,29&    1120,29&    &   1,95&   558&    1530\\  
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1764,57&    1764,49&    &   2,08&   451&    574\\
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
2204,36&    2204,21&    &   1,86&   141&    188\\
\hline
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1460,81&    1460,75&    $^{40}$K&   1,73&   422&    738\\
\hline
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
74,71&  \multirow{2}{*}{rtg}&    \multirow{2}{*}{$^{214}$Pb}& 1,15&   2321&   34035\\
\cline{1-1} \cline{4-6}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
84,54&  &   &   1,22&   891&    16412\\

        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
        \end{tabular}

    \label{Cs}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I tried according to Bernard's script another table and TeXMaker doesn't translate it, so I can't see where are mistakes. Do you know please where is a problem? Thank you

```
\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
    \caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{V{4}c|c|c|c|cV{4}}
        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}        
       \rowcolor{gray!25}      
             \multicolumn{1}{V{4}cV{4.8}}|}{Pozorovaný objekt} & \multicolumn{1}{cV{3cm}|}{Určená hodnota $E$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{cV{3.5cm}|}{Tabelovaná hodnota energie $E$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{cV{1.5cm}|}{$\mathit{FWHM}$ [keV]} &\multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}m{1.2cm}V{4}}{\textit{NET}}\\

            \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

&&&&\\[-10pt]
Energie $\gamma $-záření (FEP)& \centering  $661,68 \pm 0,02$& \centering   $661,66$& \centering    $1,5$&$70096$\\
\hline
Poloha comptonovy hrany& \centering $478 \pm 4$&\centering  477,34 (shoduje se s~teoretickou)&  &   \\
\hline
Hraniční energie dvojného comptonova rozptylu&\centering    $565 \pm 12$&\centering 554,58& &       \\
\hline
&&&&\\[-10pt]
Poloha píků zpětného rozptylu&\centering    $182 \pm 4$&\centering  184,32& &       \\

        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
        \end{tabular}

    \label{Cs}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\centering` does nothing in l c or r columns, but you have not said what the problem is with your table. You have marked the join of the thick and thin lines in blue, but have not said how you want them changed, they do not look nice but it is hard to make them look better if you want to change the line widths (I would not do that) Unrelated but do not use math italic for words, `$GROSS$` should be `$\mathrm{GROSS}$` (or simply  `GROSS`)

Comment: I would like to vertical thin lines go from the midle of vertical bold lines. 
$GROSS$ is wrong even if it is a name of quantity?

Comment: the math italic font is designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word but like a product of variables, it should never be used for any multi-letter identifiers, you can use `\mathit` or `\mathrm` to get fonts designed for words in mathematics.  Note `$\mathit{GROSS}$` is not the same as `$GROSS$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose this variant, with the `boldline` package (so needless to define a new column type): a vertical line   specified in the table preamble with `V{x}` produces a line of width x times `\arrayrulewidth`. I simplified  the code for colouring column heads with the `\rowcolor` command, and removed the unnecessary `\centering` directives in columns of type `c`. Finally, I removed every double package loading.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, boldline}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
\caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs - přirozené pozadí}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{V{4}c|c|c|c|c|cV{4}}
    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \rowcolor{gray!25}
    \multicolumn{1}{V{4}cV{2.5}}{\textit{PEAK} [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}cV{2.5}}{\centering $E_{\text{tab}}$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}cV{2.5}}{\centering Zdroj} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}cV{2.5}}{\textit{FWHM} [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}m{1.2cm}V{2.5}}{\centering \textit{NET} } & \multicolumn{1}{V{1.5}m{1.2cm}V{4}}{\textit{GROSS}}\\

    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    &&&&&\\[-10pt]
    609,35& 609,31& \multirow{4}{*}{$^{214}$Bi} & 1,38& 539& 4675\\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
    &&&&&\\[-10pt]
    1120,29& 1120,29& & 1,95& 558& 1530\\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
    &&&&&\\[-10pt]
    1764,57& 1764,49& & 2,08& 451& 574\\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
    &&&&&\\[-10pt]
    2204,36& 2204,21& & 1,86& 141& 188\\
    \hline
    &&&&&\\[-10pt]
    1460,81& 1460,75& $^{40}$K& 1,73& 422& 738\\
    \hline
    &&&&&\\[-10pt]
    74,71& \multirow{2}{*}{rtg}& \multirow{2}{*}{$^{214}$Pb}& 1,15& 2321& 34035\\
    \cline{1-1} \cline{4-6}
    &&&&&\\[-10pt]
    84,54& & & 1,22& 891& 16412\\
    \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \end{tabular}
\label{Cs}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for perfect question. Please the last question: what is an alternative of \multirow{4}{*}{$^{214}$Bi} for columns?

Comment: Do you mean for typing the isotope of bismuth? or for `\multirow`?

Comment: I mean: this   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNPbD.png to be one cell

Comment: Oh! I see. It is `\multicolumn{4}{specifier}{content}`, where specifier should be `c`, `l` or `r`, depending on the alignment you want.

Comment: Thank you I need to do more tables and I have problem with translating - I edited a question. Please can you help me?

Comment: Ican help, a litle later, but I saw severaal errors in the column heads: in `V{x}`, x has to be a *number*, not a length. For instance `V{2.5}` means a vertical rule of width equal to 2.5 times normal rule width, i.e. 2.5 × 0.4pt=1pt (~0.35mm). It does not have to be used with `|`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll correct it by myself I hope. Thank you for your help again.

Answer (score 4):

- indicated graphical problem can not be solved.
- use thick lines as you like to have to may not appear as nice table design. better is not used thick vertical lines

off-topic

- it is sufficient to load each package only once
- instead use `\cellcolor` in each cell in row is simpler use ˙\rowcolor`
- vertical spacing of your cell is strange. why you not exploit loaded `cellspace`?
- why you not use `mchem` package for writing chemical elements?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, cellspace, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{Sc?}{#1}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \footnotesize
    \caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs - přirozené pozadí}
    \label{Cs}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{?Sc? *{4}{Sc|}c?}
        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
        \rowcolor{gray!25}
\multicolumn{1}{?c?}{$PEAK$ [keV]}
    & \mc{$E_{tab}$ [keV]}
        & \mc{Zdroj}
            & \mc{$FWHM$ [keV]}
                & \mc{$NET$}
                    & \mc{$GROSS$}\\
        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
%    &&&&&\\[-10pt]
609,35  & 609,31& \multirow{5.2}{*}{$^{214}$Bi} & 1,38&   539&    4675\\
        \cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
%&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1120,29&    1120,29&    &   1,95&   558&    1530\\
    \cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
%&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1764,57&    1764,49&    &   2,08&   451&    574\\
        \cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
%&&&&&\\[-10pt]
2204,36&    2204,21&    &   1,86&   141&    188\\
        \hline
%&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1460,81&    1460,75&    $^{40}$K&   1,73&   422&    738\\
        \hline
%&&&&&\\[-10pt]
74,71 &  \multirow{2}{*}{rtg} & \multirow{2.4}{*}{$^{214}$Pb}& 1,15&   2321&   34035\\
        \cline{1-1} \cline{4-6}
%&&&&&\\[-10pt]
84,54&  &   &   1,22&   891&    16412\\
        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**

i would redesign your table to:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}                       % <--- new
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}                  % <--- new
\usepackage[group-minimum-digits=4] {siunitx}   % <--- new
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \caption{Zářič \ce{^{137}Cs} - přirozené pozadí}    % <--- changed
    \label{Cs}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.2] % <--- changed
                S[table-format=4.2] % <--- changed
                c
                S[table-format=1.2] % <--- changed
                S[table-format=4.0] % <--- changed
                S[table-format=5.0] % <--- changed
                }
    \toprule    % <--- changed
{\thead{\textit{PEAK}\\ {[keV]}}}   % <--- changed
            & {\thead{$E_{\text{tab}}$\\ {[keV]}}}  % <--- changed
                      & {\textit{Zdroj}}    % <--- changed
                            & {\thead{\textit{FWHM}\\ {[keV]}}} % <--- changed
                                    & {\textit{NET}}    % <--- changed
                                            & {\textit{GROSS}}\\    % <--- changed
        \midrule    % <--- changed
    609,35  &  609,31 & \multirow{4}{*}{\ce{^{214}Bi}}  % <--- changed
                            & 1,38  & 539   & 4675  \\
    1120,29 & 1120,29 &     & 1,95  & 558   & 1530  \\
    1764,57 & 1764,49 &     & 2,08  & 451   &  574  \\
    2204,36 & 2204,21 &     & 1,86  & 141   &  188  \\
        \addlinespace   % <--- new
    1460,81&    1460,75&    \ce{^{40}K}                 % <--- changed
                            & 1,73  & 422   &  738  \\
        \addlinespace   % <--- new
    74,71 &  {\multirow{2}{*}{rtg}}
                      & \multirow{2}{*}{\ce{^{214}Pb}}  % <--- changed
                            & 1,15  & 2321  & 34035 \\
    84,54 &           &     & 1.22  &  891  & 16412 \\
       \bottomrule  % <--- changed
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful comments! (+1). However, the graphical problem can be solved, see my answer using boldline.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for comment! and +1 for `boldline`. in your answer. i wasn't aware for this package.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tabular{\shorthandoff{-}}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]\footnotesize
    \caption{Zářič $^{137}$Cs - přirozené pozadí}
    \centering
\doublerulesepcolor{black}
        \begin{tabular}{?c||c|c|c|c|c?}
        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}

\multicolumn{1}{?c|}{\cellcolor{gray!25}$PEAK$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\centering \cellcolor{gray!25}$E_{tab}$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\centering Zdroj \cellcolor{gray!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\centering \cellcolor{gray!25}$FWHM$ [keV]} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1.2cm}|}{\centering $NET$ \cellcolor{gray!25}} & \multicolumn{1}{m{1.2cm}?}{$GROSS$ \cellcolor{gray!25}}\\         

\Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
609,35& 609,31& \multirow{4}{*}{$^{214}$Bi} & 1,38&   539&    4675\\ 
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1120,29&    1120,29&    &   1,95&   558&    1530\\  
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1764,57&    1764,49&    &   2,08&   451&    574\\
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-6}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
2204,36&    2204,21&    &   1,86&   141&    188\\
\hline
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
1460,81&    1460,75&    $^{40}$K&   1,73&   422&    738\\
\hline
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
74,71&  \multirow{2}{*}{rtg}&    \multirow{2}{*}{$^{214}$Pb}& 1,15&   2321&   34035\\
\cline{1-1} \cline{4-6}
&&&&&\\[-10pt]
84,54&  &   &   1,22&   891&    16412\\

        \Xhline{4\arrayrulewidth}
        \end{tabular}

    \label{Cs}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is possible to make vertical lines in the first row bold?

Comment: Or... does it look better?

Comment: There is a bold line now, try it and see how you like it.

Comment: If you'd like a thiner line it is possible.